# Nginx monitor current connections

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

I am just starting learning Nginx webserver. I have question regarding few parameters which I know apache has, but I cannot find something similar in Nginx.

I used to monitor idle workers in apache with http:/host/server-status. Unfortunately I didn't find the way how to monitor idle workers in nginx.

As I understood Nginx has one global worker (worker_processes) which can server 1024 worker_connections. I hope I am get it correctly.

But how can I measure the current load on Nginx. How many from 1024 worker_connections I use currently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent for nginx is [HttpStubStatusModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpStubStatusModule). And there is a [Munin plugin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins/nginx).

nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen 127.0.0.1;
   server_name localhost;
   location /nginx_status {
           stub_status on;
           access_log   off;
           allow 127.0.0.1;
           deny all;
   }
}
```

And if you have an other ssl server, add :

```
server {
   listen 127.0.0.1:443;
   ssl....
   server_name localhost;
   location /nginx_status_ssl {
           stub_status on;
           access_log   off;
           allow 127.0.0.1;
           deny all;
   }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I have another one server section for https connection, the problem now is even connection to nginx_status it tries to transfer thought ssl and meanwhile I have error messages 400 Bad Request. Do you know what I missed?